# How to pass table name as parameter to database query in Kohana 3

Tags: php, database, parameters, kohana

I have a complex 3 layer query in wich I`d liked to pass **table name** as parameter.
I use code **like**  this:

```
DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT 
    SUM(volume) AS `volumeTotal`, 
    MIN(volume) AS `volumeMin`, 
    MAX(volume) AS `volumeMax`, 
    AVG(volume) AS `volumeAverage`, 
    STD(volume) AS `volumeSD`
FROM (
    SELECT TIMEDIFF (DT,CAST( @dt AS DATETIME )) AS Ival, CAST( @dt AS DATETIME ) AS `start` , @dt := DT AS `stop` , `volume`
    FROM ( SELECT @dt := NULL) dt, 
    ( SELECT * FROM  :table WHERE id = :XID) vals
ORDER BY dt ASC) vI')
    ->param(':table', $tableName)
    ->param(':XID', $ID) 
    ->execute();
```

It is not suitable for me to use query builder for this (and I think it is not optimal way).
Of course, I may input parameters into query directly like "`.$tableName.`", but I think there should be a more correct way.

The question is:

How to pass table name as parameter to database query using Kohana?

Comment: You're already doing it `->param(':table', $tableName)`

Comment: Inserted DB::expr() in the wrong place. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `DB::expr($tableName)` instead of `$tableName`.